# Unable to connect MongoDb database

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

When trying to connect MongoDb database from MongoChef after running `mongod.exe` I am getting this error:

```
Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27018, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by

 {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect}}]
```

Comment: If the driver initially connects then later cannot connect, then that points to some networking issue. It may be intermittent and not happen all the time. But from the drivers perspective it is timing out trying to select a server. The log message just shows you the current view of the servers after selection has failed, which is it is in the process of connecting to the mongo1 node.

Comment: Connection refused means the operating system on the destination actively refused the connection because nothing was listening on that port.

Comment: I have check ports are not occupied and are allowed on my local system. Previously it was working fine but suddenly when i trying to connect any database its timeout. I haven't change anything at mongoDb configuration level.